# Is the sentence "We are invested" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is the sentence "We are invested" correct?

I found it in a blog and was wondering whether it is correct. I do not want to discuss the usage, but just if the combination of "are" + "invested" is grammatically correct and has the correct sentence structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is correct

To be invested is marketing speak for being involved/committed

[Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/invested)

> 2.a. To spend or devote for future advantage or benefit: invested much time and energy in getting a good education.
>
> b. To devote morally or psychologically, as to a purpose; commit: "Men of our generation are invested in what they do, women in what we are" (Shana Alexander).

Example: [We are invested](http://www.fcsinteractive.com/news/bny-mellon-we-are-invested.aspx)

> A new multimedia ad campaign would be a logical outcome of the brand review. But the team realized they had a significant job ahead of them first: internal education. They wanted staff to be **invested** in the brand and thus worked hard to imbue employees with messaging around the simple idea of **"We Are Invested."** The message spoke to the staff in terms of their needed commitment, their responsibility as brand ambassadors, to focus on positive outcomes and to strive for excellence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be, if you are using *[invested](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invest)* to mean:-

> [Middle French investir, from Old Italian investire, from Latin, to
>   surround] :  to surround with troops or ships so as to prevent escape
>   or entry

as in "*We are invested by barbarians.*"

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you, that's the only meaning I could think. Unfortunately in the blog was used to refer as "business investment" so I guess is incorrect. Am I right?